# Crash in CFRelease when running XCTest unit tests on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, unit-testing, memory-management, xctest

This only seems to happen when running unit tests against one of my view controllers, and it's pretty random. Sometimes the test will pass, but most of the time it crashes in the same place.

The following is the stack trace from Xcode:

```
#0  0x000000010e66727c in CFRelease ()
#1  0x000000011b4b1e00 in 0x11b4b1e00 ()
#2  0x000000010e667268 in CFRelease ()
#3  0x000000010de060b8 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#4  0x000000011b325c23 in -[XCTestCase performTest:] ()
#5  0x000000011b3238d1 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#6  0x000000011b3238d1 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#7  0x000000011b3238d1 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#8  0x000000011b310adc in __25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke ()
#9  0x000000011b3312e3 in -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] ()
#10 0x000000011b310a28 in -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] ()
#11 0x000000011b311787 in -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] ()
#12 0x000000011b359b23 in _XCTestMain ()
#13 0x000000010e6c2ffc in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#14 0x000000010e6b8c85 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#15 0x000000010e6b83e2 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x000000010e6b7e08 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x0000000111687ad2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x000000010efad30d in UIApplicationMain ()
#19 0x000000010b76c134 in main at /Users/abc/Projects/xyz/Supporting Files/main.m:14
#20 0x000000011060292d in start ()
#21 0x000000011060292d in start ()
```

The assembly code near the breakpoint has a reference to a string that seems to be suggesting that a `NULL` argument was passed to `CFRelease`:

```
    0x10e667252 <+1170>: callq  0x10e653af0               ; CFAllocatorDeallocate
    0x10e667257 <+1175>: cmpq   %rbx, %r13
    0x10e66725a <+1178>: je     0x10e667013               ; <+595>
    0x10e667260 <+1184>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x10e667263 <+1187>: callq  0x10e666dc0               ; <+0>
    0x10e667268 <+1192>: jmp    0x10e667013               ; <+595>
    0x10e66726d <+1197>: leaq   0x329469(%rip), %rax      ; "*** CFRelease() called with NULL ***"
    0x10e667274 <+1204>: movq   %rax, 0x35994d(%rip)      ; gCRAnnotations + 8
    0x10e66727b <+1211>: int3   
->  0x10e66727c <+1212>: jmp    0x10e667282               ; <+1218>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this could possibly happen?

I'm using Xcode 7.1.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is roughly what the crashing test looks like:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.viewControllerMocks = @{
    FixtureViewControllerKey: OCMClassMock([UIViewController class]),
    // ... more UIViewController mocks
};
self.menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithInnerNavigationController:self.navigationController initialViewControllerKey:FixtureViewControllerKey viewControllers:self.viewControllerMocks];
(void)self.menuViewController.view;

[self simulateTapOnMenuItemWithTitle:@"Some button"];
XCTAssertEqual(self.navigationController.viewControllers[0],
               self.viewControllerMocks[MenuViewControllerSomeKey]);
```

This is how `simulateTapOnMenuItemWithTitle:` is defined:

```
- (void)simulateTapOnMenuItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    UIButton *button = [self.menuViewController.view testsFindButtonWithTitle:title];
    [button testsSimulateTap];
}

// Helper methods defined in a UIView category

- (UIView *)testsFindSubviewUsingBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *subview))block {
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if (block(subview)) {
            return subview;
        }
        UIView *foundSubview = [subview testsFindSubviewUsingBlock:block];
        if (foundSubview != nil) {
            return foundSubview;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIButton *)testsFindButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    return (UIButton *)[self testsFindSubviewUsingBlock:^BOOL(UIView *subview) {
        return [subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [((UIButton *)subview).titleLabel.text isEqualToString:title];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please include the code of the test case which is causing the crash, and maybe also the code which is being tested (if relevant).

Comment: @MichałCiuba: Added my test's code above, please have a look.